# How to implement Next-auth withAuth middleware with Nextjs App Server side fetching

Tags: authentication, next.js, next-auth

I have create an api routes that cover with withAuth middleware of next-auth like this. It basic ly required auth for every api and /dashboard routes.

However when using server side fetching, it is not auth so it cannot reach api whatsoever. Is there a way to overcome this?

```js
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default withAuth(
  async function middleware(req) {
    const token = await getToken({ req });
    const isAuth = !!token;
    const isAuthPage =
      req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/login") ||
      req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/register");
    const isApiPage = req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/api");

    if (isAuthPage) {
      if (isAuth) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", req.url));
      }

      return null;
    }

    if (isApiPage) {
      if (isAuth) {
        return NextResponse.next();
      }
    }

    if (!isAuth) {
      let from = req.nextUrl.pathname;
      if (req.nextUrl.search) {
        from += req.nextUrl.search;
      }

      return NextResponse.redirect(
        new URL(`/login?from=${encodeURIComponent(from)}`, req.url)
      );
    }
  },
  {
    callbacks: {
      authorized() {
        // This is a work-around for handling redirect on auth pages.
        // We return true here so that the middleware function above
        // is always called.
        return true;
      },
    },
  }
);

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/api/:path*",
    "/dashboard/:path*",
    "/editor/:path*",
    "/login",
    "/register",
  ],
};
```

This a simple server side fetching with nextjs app directory

```js
async function getUser(id: string) {
  // Fetch data from your API here.
  const user = await fetch(absoluteUrl("/api/user/" + id), {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    next: {
      revalidate: 1, // In seconds
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.ok) return res.json() as Promise<UserDetail>;
      else return null;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
      return null;
    });
  return user;
}
```

I am thinking about put an extra cookie to authorized on middleware. But I believe there is more proficient way to do this